# Pandas Date Time subraction - assigning nan values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

If I have code as below,

```
df['variance'] = (pd.to_datetime(df.last_date) - pd.to_datetime(df.first_date)) / np.timedelta64(1, 'M')
```

This gives me number of months, but if one of the columns does not have a date and the result for this code for that value is NaN, is there a way where I can assign the value of the NaN to a certain value like 'Void'?

So instead of the number of months, I would see void as the value? Thanks
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
df = df.fillna(value='Void')
```

Comment: Is there anything I can add to the code to do this in same line?

Comment: @Chris90 wrap your call `(pd.to_datetime(df.last_date) - pd.to_datetime(df.first_date)) / np.timedelta64(1, 'M')).fillna('void')`